# How to add Cache-Control: no-store in authenticated pages in DotNetNuke 5.4.4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, cache-control, dotnetnuke-5

I would like to know what is the best way to include `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` in authenticated pages in DotNetNuke 5.4.4. In fact, I want to prevent caching in IE6/7 and FireFox as well.

Your suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way to do that is with a skin object that adds the proper headers to the page. Slightly more work would be to create a http module for that.

By default you cannot do that in DNN (the host setting works on the entire application).